# Existing Angular Project with node, bower, and now Gulp

Tags: html, angularjs, build, gulp

So my project seed had originally used Grunt, but that got destroyed and can not help with creating a build in a folder destination. So I am trying (in a quick way) to add Gulp as I like the way it works over grunt. That said, my project is Angular based and has a number of dependencies from Kendo UI to Bootstrap to Font Awesome.

So here is my dilemma - I can get pieces to go together with my gulp file I have been trying to build, but at the root, I need to change some things so that I can simple copy all my files to a destination location and if need be, reference dependencies via URL's as I am using bower and node components for these dependencies. For now, I don't care if I can lint, concat, minify, etc... I simply want to copy a folder to my server and have it work. I am working within a Windows environment and because of the file path lengths of node and bower components, this isn't feasible and some routing and injection bust for Angular.

My file structure is shown here in the screenshots:

[image]

And this shows how my controllers and views correspond with one another by naing convention:

[image]

And lastly, I understand that I can revise my references in my index.html to help with my scripts and all, but not sure how to go about that with gulp despite my search efforts.

Any of you able to show me some ways to solve this so that I can get a quick build out and go back to later to add further functionality?

All help is much appreciated!

My current gulpfile.js:

```
/*!
 * gulp
 * $ npm install gulp-ruby-sass gulp-autoprefixer gulp-minify-css gulp-jshint gulp-concat gulp-uglify gulp-imagemin gulp-notify gulp-rename gulp-livereload gulp-cache del --save-dev
 */

// Load plugins
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    // sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    uncss = require('gulp-uncss'),
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    svgmin = require('gulp-svgmin'),
    // angular-filesort = require('gulp-angular-filesort'),
    // bower-files = require('gulp-main-bower-files'),
    // livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    del = require('del');

// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  // return sass('src/styles/main.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
  return gulp.src('app/ppt/styles/main.css')  
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/styles'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/styles'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});

// Scripts
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/ppt/scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));
});

// Images
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/ppt/assets/images/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/images'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Images task complete' }));
});

// Clean
gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
    del(['dist/assets/styles', 'dist/assets/scripts', 'dist/assets/images'], cb)
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.start('styles', 'scripts', 'images');
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {

  // Watch .scss files
  gulp.watch('src/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);

  // Watch .js files
  gulp.watch('src/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);

  // Watch image files
  gulp.watch('src/images/**/*', ['images']);

  // Create LiveReload server
  livereload.listen();

  // Watch any files in dist/, reload on change
  gulp.watch(['dist/**']).on('change', livereload.changed);

});
```

Comment: I believe my biggest challenges here in trying to get a proper build that can run is my script references.

Comment: Anyone add anything?